# Doubt while solving a third order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions, homogeneous-equation

I solved $$y(x) = -3e^{-3x}+3\cos2x - 2\sin2x$$
And reached
$$y^{(3)}+3y''+4y'+12y=0$$

Now it's graph looks periodic on the right side of the $x$-axis .
I was wondering under what conditions is     $$y(x)\approx 3\cos2x-2\sin2x$$

Comment: I am guessing when $x$ is sufficiently large so that $\exp(-3x)$ gets very small (note that I have not looked at the validated of you ODE etc)

Comment: Take any $x \geq 1$. $-3e^{-3}=-0.15$ while the other portion is $-3.07$ that is to say $0$ times larger